# Different size of same image on Web on Android

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have an image like test.png.

I need to purchase that image from the web and in another location I need to pick the same image from the drawable.

The problem is that I have the same png on the web and in the drawable. When I show the image I have in the drawable, it shows in the right size but when I get it from the web, it appears smaller.
Just to make it clear, it's just an example of my problem... I'm not actually using the same image, they are different images but with the same size. To verify, I've uploaded the same image on the web and on drawable and found that the same image appears with different sizes.
What do I need to do to make both appear like on drawable mode?

I've verified this:

When I get the image I've saved in SD card using:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Fle directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
File file = new File(directory, "teste.png");
File InputStream streamIn;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmapfactory.decodeStream(streamin);
ImageView image = new ImageView(c);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The image appears bigger than this way:

```
Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "teste.png").getAbsolutePath());
ImageView image = new ImageView(c);
image.setImageDrawable(img);
```

But in the first mode it appears smaller than when I get the image directly from the resource drawable using getResouces.getDrawable...

Comment: You need to provide more context to get help with this question. What have you tried? How are you actually displaying each version (code helps!)? When you 'upload' the image, what are you using? (That could affect the image itself.)

Comment: Even if you are using the same images, they will have different sizes when converted into a drawable as they are created with Context.getResources() along with other parameters such as the scaleType etc. Esp when displayed on a webview, you can be affected by view point adjustments etc. That being said, just save the image and get it back the same way and you will be fine since they will be displaying essentially the same file.

Comment: I do not understand the question exactly. When you display the image from resources it looks good but when the download looks smaller?

Comment: The image from the drawable folder i get with getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.teste); The image from the web, i get URL url = new URL(path) and then  i get url.openStream() to get the image. I store it into Envionment.getExternalStorageDirectory() with FileOutputStream. The code is on the other machine without internet, so i've no how to copy all the code. Sorry.

Comment: Brais, yes. From drawable its good and when i download it, save it on sd card and then try to show the image, it get smaller. In both ways i use ImageView to show. But from drawable i get with getResources()... Edison, is there some way to make them appear as the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this code to reproduce the error:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

try {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("tag-logo-android.png"));
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ll.addView(image);

    image = new ImageView(this);
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-logo-android.png").openStream(), null);
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    ll.addView(image);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem isn't the source of the image. The problem is that `Drawable` ignores screen density. This code works:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

try {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("tag-logo-android.png"));
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ll.addView(image);

    image = new ImageView(this);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-logo-android.png").openStream());
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ll.addView(image);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In your case you can use:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a Bitmap object instead Drawable to solve your problem.